# Error when searching a vector for any instances of an object

Tags: c++, vector

I have a vector called entities. I want to check if it contains any instances of the class NPC.  This is what I have so far.

```
if (std::find(entities.begin(), entities.end(), NPC()) != entities.end()) 
    std::cout << "contains NPCs" << std::endl;
```

When I try to compile this, I get the error, "binary '==': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const NPC'".

Also, can anyone show me how to check for the opposite? That is, how to check if the vector *doesn't* contain any NPCs?

Edit:

I added this to my header file

```
inline bool operator==(const NPC& lhs, const NPC& rhs)
{
    return std::is_base_of<Entity, NPC>::value;
}
```

But I get the error, 'std::is_base_of': invalid template argument for '_Der'"

I thought I was telling it to check if the NPC is a subclass of the Entity class, but maybe I'm doing it wrong. Even if that was the case, would that even solve the problem? Sorry, I'm just not familiar with operaror overloading. I'm very new to c++.

Comment: Your post appears to be missing a [mcve].

Comment: You need to tell the compiler how to compare NPCs by overloading the `==` operator

Comment: You should use `std::find_if` suppying method that will return `true` of `false` depending on whether entity is an instance of NPC or not.

Comment: Find will compare the value you passed in to the elements in the vector.  Almost certain your error is NPC doesn't have operator== defined properly for it.

Comment: also, to find the opposite, change the test from != entities.end() to == entities.end(), then your if-body will execute if it was not found.

Comment: @Tyler Any chance you can show me how to do that? I've only been programming in c++ for a couple of weeks.

Comment: *how to check if the vector doesn't contain any NPCs?* -- If `entities.end()` is returned, then none exists.  You could / should have easily seen this if you removed the `if` and just called `std::find_if()`, and then [read the documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) on what `std::find_if` returns

Comment: @Gaud check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), all you need is something like `inline bool operator==(const NPC& lhs, const NPC& rhs){//whatever makes two NPCs equal, return true or false}`

Comment: More details required to provide a useful answer.  For example `entities` is a `vector` of what, exactly? I think `std::find_if` might be more useful here. You can specify your own comparison function rather than use `operator==`. `operator==` doesn't make sense here because you are not looking for equality.

Comment: @user4581301 entities is a vector of classes (or objects) that extend the Entity class. NPC is a class that extends the Entity class.

Comment: Be explicit. Is it `vector<Entity *>`, `vector<<unique_ptr<Entity *>>`, or some other variant? These nagging little details matter.

Comment: @user4581301 It's vector<Entity *>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion: `operator==` is the wrong tool to use here because this is not testing equality. This is a test to see if a given `Entity` is an `NPC`. Because of this I suggest `std::find_if`. `find_if` allows us to specify different tests.

The simplest, easiest to understand test I can come up with is

```
bool isNPC(const Entity * const & entity)
{
    // a dynamic_cast returns nullptr if entity cannot be cast to an NPC *
    return dynamic_cast<const NPC*>(entity) != nullptr;
}
```

And I can't think of a good reason to go any more complicated than this.

`isNPC` could and probably should be a lambda, but to make this as clear as possible I'm leaving it a free function. Template this function and you can use it for any child of `Entity`, `Monster` for example .

Usage looks like:

```
void test(const std::vector<Entity *> & entities)
{
    if (std::find_if(entities.begin(), entities.end(), isNPC) != entities.end())
    {
        std::cout << "found NPC\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "No NPCs\n";
    }
}
```

Caveat: This will catch subclasses of `NPC` as well.

[Documentation on `std::find_if` and family.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) `find_if_not` should be of interest to you as well.

## Edit

Lambda version (C++14 or more recent. It's an ugly sucker not much better than the free function version in C++11):

```
if (std::find_if(entities.begin(), 
                 entities.end(), 
                 [](auto & entity)->bool
                 {
                     return dynamic_cast<const NPC*>(entity) != nullptr;
                 }) != entities.end())
{
    std::cout << "found\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "not found\n";
}
```

The reason I like the free function, as I hinted above, is you can

```
template <class TYPE>
bool isChild(const Entity * const & entity)
{
    // a dynamic_cast returns nullptr if entity cannot be cast to an NPC *
    return dynamic_cast<const TYPE*>(entity) != nullptr;
}
```

and then

```
std::find_if(entities.begin(), entities.end(), isChild<Ninja>)
```

to go looking for Ninjas. You don't have to keep writing the same darn function, or lambda equivalent, over and over for each type you find yourself searching for.

If you use it once or twice, go lambda. If you suspect you'll be looking for more children, template. Unless there are templated lambdas out there now. Those would be cool.

Comment: That's great, but is there a way to make it NOT catch subclasses of NPC? Also, can you show how to make isNPC a lambda?

Comment: @Gaud "is there a way to make it NOT catch subclasses of NPC?" Take a wild guess what `find_if_not` does. As for the lambda, that'll be up in an edit in a moment.

Comment: I agree, the free function is better, but is there a way for the search function to exclude the base classes of NPC? I can't take a wild guess. I have no idea. Please, if there's a way, I'll give your answer a check mark, I just don't want it to include other classes that extend NPC.

Comment: My apologies. I misread your first comment. `find_if_not` will not work for that. Because subclasses of `NPC` are `NPC`s, I don't have a good way to filter them out.

Comment: That leads to a thought. If you don't want subclasses of `NPC` to register as `NPC`s, why are they subclasses? Kinda makes a mess of the whole is-a relationship.

Comment: I made the Player class extend NPC because they share a lot of the same movement and collision detection. NPCs are really just the enemies and I want the game to know when the player has defeated all of the enemies.

Comment: In that case consider making a class  that provides the commonalities and have `NPC` and `Player` extend it.